# Auto bed leveling offset issue

Tags: marlin, skr-v1.3, ezabl

I'm using an Ender 3 with a new upgraded board SKR 1.3 Marlin bugfix 2.0 auto bed leveling I use EZABL.

for the EZABL I followed their [tutorial](https://th3dstudio.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043293552?seq_no=2) for Marlin 2.0 since I don't use the unified firmware.

Offset info :

`#define NOZZLE_TO_PROBE_OFFSET { 50, -2, 0 }`

`#define MIN_PROBE_EDGE 20`

I did try to follow this helpful [guide](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/8153/how-to-set-z-probe-boundary-limits-in-firmware-when-using-automatic-bed-leveling)

I don't know much about programming so when he said:

> "As this is the part that defines the array values, you first need to make an array (note that this is a simple solution that many people should be able to understand with limited programming skills, more elegant solutions use the XYZ struct to access the X, Y or Z properties):"

`constexpr int nozzle_to_probe_offset[] = NOZZLE_TO_PROBE_OFFSET;`

`#define PROBE_X_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER nozzle_to_probe_offset[0]`

`#define PROBE_Y_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER nozzle_to_probe_offset[1]`

I don't understand where to put the lines above and what value to put.

update:
error message on compiling
[image]
Config.h : https://pastebin.com/w7CC5eaC
Config_adv.h : https://pastebin.com/qep34T1h

Comment: Please look into the guide again it is updated to the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to adjust the area yourself for Marlin 2.0, please look into [probe.h](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/2.0.x/Marlin/src/module/probe.h) and into [this answer](/a/8154).

You only need to enable the offsets:

```
#if PROBE_SELECTED && !IS_KINEMATIC
  #define MIN_PROBE_EDGE_LEFT MIN_PROBE_EDGE
  #define MIN_PROBE_EDGE_RIGHT MIN_PROBE_EDGE
  #define MIN_PROBE_EDGE_FRONT MIN_PROBE_EDGE
  #define MIN_PROBE_EDGE_BACK MIN_PROBE_EDGE
#endif
```