# MESH_INSET vs PROBING_MARGIN

Tags: marlin, bed-leveling, 3dtouch

I've been tinkering with my 3DTouch (basically a BLTouch clone) on my CoreXY and have been trying to set up UBL in Marlin. There are a few configurations I haven't been able to find any useful resources about, as I'm having a hard time understanding and tackling some of them.

I do not understand `MESH_INSET` and `PROBING_MARGIN` and/or their difference.

Also couldn't find anything useful about `SEGMENT_LEVELED_MOVES` and `LEVELED_SEGMENT_LENGTH`.

Comment: You can find an answer on `PROBING_MARGIN` and `MESH_INSET`  [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/14937).