# BLTouch not covering the whole bed area

Tags: marlin, bed-leveling, bltouch, z-probe

My problem is that the BLtouch doesn't probe the whole bed, in which the probe starts from the left edge and stops at the middle of the bed. I'm using Marlin 2 software and this the code in the configuration.h file:

```
  #define BLTOUCH

/**
 * Touch-MI Probe by hotends.fr
 *
 * This probe is deployed and activated by moving the X-axis to a magnet at the edge of the bed.
 * By default, the magnet is assumed to be on the left and activated by a home. If the magnet is
 * on the right, enable and set TOUCH_MI_DEPLOY_XPOS to the deploy position.
 *
 * Also requires: BABYSTEPPING, BABYSTEP_ZPROBE_OFFSET, Z_SAFE_HOMING,
 *                and a minimum Z_HOMING_HEIGHT of 10.
 */
//#define TOUCH_MI_PROBE
#if ENABLED(TOUCH_MI_PROBE)
  #define TOUCH_MI_RETRACT_Z 0.5                  // Height at which the probe retracts
  //#define TOUCH_MI_DEPLOY_XPOS (X_MAX_BED + 2)  // For a magnet on the right side of the bed
  //#define TOUCH_MI_MANUAL_DEPLOY                // For manual deploy (LCD menu)
#endif

// A probe that is deployed and stowed with a solenoid pin (SOL1_PIN)
//#define SOLENOID_PROBE

// A sled-mounted probe like those designed by Charles Bell.
//#define Z_PROBE_SLED
//#define SLED_DOCKING_OFFSET 5  // The extra distance the X axis must travel to pickup the sled. 0 should be fine but you can push it further if you'd like.

// A probe deployed by moving the x-axis, such as the Wilson II's rack-and-pinion probe designed by Marty Rice.
//#define RACK_AND_PINION_PROBE
#if ENABLED(RACK_AND_PINION_PROBE)
  #define Z_PROBE_DEPLOY_X  X_MIN_POS
  #define Z_PROBE_RETRACT_X X_MAX_POS
#endif

// Duet Smart Effector (for delta printers) - https://bit.ly/2ul5U7J
// When the pin is defined you can use M672 to set/reset the probe sensivity.
//#define DUET_SMART_EFFECTOR
#if ENABLED(DUET_SMART_EFFECTOR)
  #define SMART_EFFECTOR_MOD_PIN  -1  // Connect a GPIO pin to the Smart Effector MOD pin
#endif

/**
 * Use StallGuard2 to probe the bed with the nozzle.
 * Requires stallGuard-capable Trinamic stepper drivers.
 * CAUTION: This can damage machines with Z lead screws.
 *          Take extreme care when setting up this feature.
 */
//#define SENSORLESS_PROBING

//
// For Z_PROBE_ALLEN_KEY see the Delta example configurations.
//

/**
 * Z Probe to nozzle (X,Y) offset, relative to (0, 0).
 *
 * In the following example the X and Y offsets are both positive:
 *
 *   #define NOZZLE_TO_PROBE_OFFSET { 10, 10, 0 }
 *
 *     +-- BACK ---+
 *     |           |
 *   L |    (+) P  | R <-- probe (20,20)
 *   E |           | I
 *   F | (-) N (+) | G <-- nozzle (10,10)
 *   T |           | H
 *     |    (-)    | T
 *     |           |
 *     O-- FRONT --+
 *   (0,0)
 *
 * Specify a Probe position as { X, Y, Z }
 */
#define NOZZLE_TO_PROBE_OFFSET { -43.5, -9, 0 }

// Most probes should stay away from the edges of the bed, but
// with NOZZLE_AS_PROBE this can be negative for a wider probing area.
#define MIN_PROBE_EDGE 20

// X and Y axis travel speed (mm/m) between probes
#define XY_PROBE_SPEED 800

// Feedrate (mm/m) for the first approach when double-probing (MULTIPLE_PROBING == 2)
#define Z_PROBE_SPEED_FAST HOMING_FEEDRATE_Z

// Feedrate (mm/m) for the "accurate" probe of each point
#define Z_PROBE_SPEED_SLOW (Z_PROBE_SPEED_FAST / 2)
```

I have tried changing the > #define MIN_PROBE_EDGE 20 value but nothing change.

Also this is the configuration_adv.h code:

```
#if PROBE_SELECTED && !IS_KINEMATIC
  #define MIN_PROBE_EDGE_LEFT MIN_PROBE_EDGE
  #define MIN_PROBE_EDGE_RIGHT 15
  #define MIN_PROBE_EDGE_FRONT MIN_PROBE_EDGE
  #define MIN_PROBE_EDGE_BACK MIN_PROBE_EDGE
#endif
```

I also have tried changing these values but unfortunately, nothing seems to work.

Comment: What is your probe actually doing when you run `G29`?

Comment: Have you seen this question: [How to set Z-probe boundary limits in firmware when using automatic bed leveling?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/8153/how-to-set-z-probe-boundary-limits-in-firmware-when-using-automatic-bed-leveling/)? Your probe is pretty far to the left, this is subtracted from the right to prevent damaging the printer.

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions, I found that I had to reset the mainboard and upload the new code so that the new changes could apply.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to reset the mainboard and upload the new code so that the new changes could apply.

---

*Answered by OP, copied from a comment on the question…*