# How center the nozzle before start printing

Tags: ultimaker-cura, g-code, corexy

I have a BLV Core XY, I'm trying to print different models, but the machine moves the center once it goes to start the process.

This is my G-code of the beginning:

```
G21
G90
M82
M107
G28

M413 S1 ;Power-loss recovery

;M190 S60    ;bed heat on
G34              ;Auto Z Level
G29              ;Bed Levelling

G28 Z
 
G1 Z2 F240
G1 X2 Y10 F1200
G1 Z0.2 F240
G92 E0.0
G1 Y150 E15.0 F1000.0 ; intro line
G1 X2.3 F5000
G1 Y10 E30 F1200.0 ; intro line
G92 E0.0

M117 Printing...
```

[image: one]

[image: two]

However, if I do a simple command like, to send the `(0,0)` on Z axis, it happens fine.

[image: center]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your bed incorrectly in the firmware.

First line you print is at X=2, while it is printed a couple of centimeters from the edge. Second the final cube is not in the center of the bed while it presumably is sliced in the center.

You should look into the definition of the bed size, the end stop offsets and the probe offsets to fix this. A detailed question and answer is found in [How to set Z-probe boundary limits in firmware when using automatic bed leveling?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/8153/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I not have the code to make this changes, the person who assemble the machine never share that.

Comment: That is unfortunate, but if you read into Marlin firmware updating and setting up the config file and if you have some interest in computers, coding and unloading over USB or through MicroSD card you should be able to do this. There are lots of movies that explain step-by-step what to do. You only need some basic information on your printer and the electronics. There are questions here but you may always ask yours and we will help you or direct to previous answers!

Comment: Sure, I'm a system engineer, I know how to write code, but I never before had been the chance to study marlin, I would wish to change some things, but I will try to get the firmware made by the person who assemble the machine, then, I could start to test new marlin firmware update.