# Ender 3 CR Touch Bed Levelling X axis offset

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling, glass-bed, ender3

I upgraded my Ender 3 with the CR Touch, and updated the firmware (contacted Creality directly to get the correct version). I got Marlin 2.0.6. However when I try the bed levelling feature the first point (nearest to the origin), always starts with the probe out of the range of the bed. While going down the nozzle hits the bed and the procedure is aborted. Not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: Your probe offset is incorrect or the bed probe area is configured incorrectly, [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/8153/how-to-set-z-probe-boundary-limits-in-firmware-when-using-automatic-bed-leveling/8154) shows how bed probe area is set.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Its a bit weird that the bin file I got from creality had that configured incorrectly though